# Login Page iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, authentication

I've done all the necessary pages etc for my app now. It uses JSON parsers to retrieve information.

I'm now stuck on the login of the app as users will need to login to use the app. How do I need to approach this and are there any tutorials that demonstrates a simple login and pushes into the main app?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you building a webapp, or native? the tag xcode makes me believe a native app, while you writing page of an webapp

Comment: Login in where? Do you have to check the login credentials on a remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do it myself, but I think you could use Web View at start to retrieve login, password and then send it to your server to verify. You do it the same way as in usual browser. Or you can use usual view and then send info to server using GET-POST methods of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

[ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) might be very useful for you.